# How is font-weight rendered when fonts have not been loaded?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I usually download fonts from Google via `@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto)` and then use them to tweak various elements (`h1`, `h2`, ...)

```
h1 {
    font-weight: 500;
}
h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

How is the font rendering calculated when:

- the correct weight (`500` in the case above) has not been loaded via `@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500)`? It is *extrapolated* from a base version of the font (with better or worse results)? Or *calculated* and in that case preloading `500` just helps (performance wise) but does not impact the visual aspect of a font?
- `bold` is used? Is `bold` a shortcut for a specific numeric weight? Or does a font defines itself what `bold` means in its case (it would be a specific numerical weight I guess?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### About `font-weight`

> The 'font-weight' property selects the weight of the font. The values '100' to '900' form an ordered sequence, where each number indicates a weight that is at least as dark as its predecessor. The keyword 'normal' is synonymous with '400', and 'bold' is synonymous with '700'.
>
> - [`font-weight` - W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-weight)

The above quote is taken from W3.org's Recommendation mean it is the standard to be used for all browsers.

---

### Rendering when weight isn't loaded

When a font weight isn't found, the browser is meant to follow a set of rules to find the nearest available option for it.

> Once the font family's weights are mapped onto the CSS scale, missing weights are selected as follows:
>
> - If the desired weight is less than 400, weights below the desired weight are checked in descending order followed by weights above the desired weight in ascending order until a match is found.
> - If the desired weight is greater than 500, weights above desired weight are checked in ascending order followed by weights below the desired weight in descending order until a match is found.
> - If the desired weight is 400, 500 is checked first and then the rule for desired weights less than 400 is used.
> - If the desired weight is 500, 400 is checked first and then the rule for desired weights less than 400 is used.

Now, it may seem like jargon but for your case, you just need to read the last point of it.

> - If the desired weight is 500, 400 is checked first and then the rule for desired weights less than 400 is used.

So ultimately, it will find if the base font is used, if not it will find anything lower than the base font, and then if nothing is still not found, it will try to find anything higher than it.

---

### Rendering when `bold`

The normal `font-weight` for `bold` is `700`. This does not chang once you start going up in font weights. If you want the font-weight of a piece of text that needs to be bolder than normal text, you will need to use `bolder` (or the alternative `lighter`) as the space between the base font weight and the `bolder` must always be greater unless it is at it's limit.

Below is a table of what the specific meaning of `bolder` and `lighter` is.

> Base - bolder -   lighter
>
> 100 --- 400 --- 100
>
> 200 --- 400 --- 100
>
> 300 --- 400 --- 100
>
> 400 --- 700 --- 100
>
> 500 --- 700 --- 100
>
> 600 --- 900 --- 400
>
> 700 --- 900 --- 400
>
> 800 --- 900 --- 700
>
> 900 --- 900 --- 700

Ultimately, all this information can be found in the W3.org spec.

- [`font-weight` - Fonts | W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-weight)

Comment: Thank you for the docs link, it clarifies (as well as your answer) a lot. I was not clear with my question: I was specifically wondering how the missing weights are computed (and if this imples a loss of quality or not) when there is nothing to "fill the holes" (per the docs).

Comment: Hopefully the second section "Rendering when weight isn't loaded" explains the procedure the browser goes through to replace missing weights.

Comment: The second part was very clear about bolding. What I am wondering is if I have only the base font (which is what is loaded, I belive, via a bare `@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto)`) then the other weights will need to be computed. Is this computation lossless (quality-wise) and in that case it is not obligatory to load other-than-base weights - or is it approximate and specific weights need to be loaded in order to render the font perfectly?

Comment: @WoJ i believe it just darkens the font more, but as the spec states `There is no guarantee that there will be a darker face for each of the 'font-weight' values`

Answer (score 0):

Weight defines from thin to thick characters. 400 is the same as normal, and 700 is the same as bold

As far as I'm aware the browser will set the font to the default set in CSS (if one is set) or the computers default which I think is Helvetica on Mac and on PC I think it's Arial.

The font weight would still be applied.